# Register decorator conditional based on consumer service type in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, ioc-container, simple-injector

I want to decorate `IService` in such a way that some consumers will a specific decorator based on their type, something like this:

```
container.Register<IService, Service>();
container.RegisterDecorator<IService, ServiceWithCaching>();
container.RegisterDecoratorConditional<IService, ServiceWithLogging>
  (ctx => ctx.Consumer.ServiceType == 
   typeof(IConsumerThatNeedsDecoratedService));
container.Register<IConsumerThatNeedsServiceWithLogging, Consumer1>();
container.Register<INormalConsumer, Consumer2>();
```

where both `ServiceWithCaching` and `ServiceWithLogging` take `IService` in their constructor, wrap an instance of IService, call it internally and do something else (e.g. caching, logging).

Both `Consumer1` and `Consumer2` accept `IService` in their constructor.

I want `Consumer1` to be injected an instance of `ServiceWithLogging` and `Consumer2` of `ServiceWithCaching`. The desired behvavior is that `Consumer1` will use an instance of `IService` that caches the results, while `Consumer2` will use an instance of `IService` that both caches results an logs calls.

Is it possible in Simple Injector and if not any known workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with `RegisterDecorator`, but as the [Applying decorators conditionally based on consumer](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html#applying-decorators-conditionally-based-on-consumer) section of the documentation explains, you can achieve this using `RegisterConditional`:

```
container.RegisterConditional<IService, ServiceWithLogging>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Consumer1));

container.RegisterConditional<IService, ServiceWithCaching>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType != typeof(Consumer1)
        && c.Consumer.ImplementationType != typeof(ServiceWithCaching));

container.RegisterConditional<IService, Service>(c => !c.Handled);
```